# Drools : How to remove dynamically created drl?

Tags: drools

I am working on a use case where I need to dynamically add/update/remove drls.

Here I am generating drl string using Rule Templates(with the data from a database) and adding it with the below code.

```
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieRepository kr = ks.getRepository();
        KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();
        
        kfs.write("src/main/resources/" + ruleName + ".drl", drl);
        
        KieBuilder kb = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs);
        kb.buildAll();
        
        if (kb.getResults().hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
            System.out.println(kb.getResults().toString());
        }
        KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(kr.getDefaultReleaseId());
```

Which API I should use for removing these drls?

Comment: Does the KieFileSystem `delete` method not work for you?

Comment: Yes. It worked. thanks!

Comment: Cool. I added it as an answer so it's not just a comment anymore.

Comment: Does delete drl free up ram as well ? I am also loading a rule file dynamically and would want to delete and free up ram after processing which I am not able to achived. Please find my question here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69309931/drools-rules-not-deleting-from-memory-after-run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KieFileSystem` has a `delete` method that is likely what you need. The `write` method, which you are already uses, "writes" a DRL file to the file system. The `delete` method deletes that DRL file. You'll need to specify the file path when you call the method, so it'll be necessary to keep track of those, especially if you have multiple.

Note that the method takes a vararg so you can pass multple files.

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieRepository kr = ks.getRepository();
KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();

// Write the file:        
kfs.write("src/main/resources/" + ruleName + ".drl", drl);

// Delete the file:
kfs.delete("src/main/resources/" + ruleName + ".drl");
```

Source: [KieFileSystem javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.44.0.Final/kie-api-javadoc/org/kie/api/builder/KieFileSystem.html#delete-java.lang.String...-)

Comment: Do i need to update the release id of KieContsiner after deleting a rule.

Comment: You should ask a separate question @sam . This question & answer don't use a release id.