# Drools Rules not deleting from memory after run

Tags: java, memory-leaks, drools, kie

We are using Drools Business Rule Engine in one of our modules  and the use case is a different set of rules (loaded from excel file) for each data set which runs as a Spring batch job.

We see that for each batch job that is run the rules loaded by drools are not being cleared from memory which is resulting in a memory leak (Confirmed using yourkit profiler).

Our code to read the rules and create the KieContainer is something like this :

```
private static KieFileSystem getKieFileSystem(String rulesFileName,String tenant,String filePath) throws Exception {
        log.debug("inside getKieFileSystem method.");
        log.debug("tenant is:: " + tenant + ", file name is:: " + rulesFileName);
        //TO-DO decide whether base path will come from base.properties of framework or
        //if it will be read from application.properties of this project
        log.debug("filePath:: " + filePath);
        
        log.debug("final filepath ::: " + filePath + tenant + "/" + rulesFileName);

        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
        kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newFileResource(filePath+tenant+"//"+rulesFileName+""));
        
        log.debug("end of getKieFileSystem method.");
        return kieFileSystem;
    }

public static KieContainer getKieContainer(String rulesFileName, String tenant, String filePath) throws Exception {
        log.debug("inside getKieContainer method.");
        log.debug("Create container...");
        
        getKieRepository();
        KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(getKieFileSystem(rulesFileName,tenant,filePath));
        kb.buildAll();
        
        KieModule kieModule = kb.getKieModule();
        KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
        
        log.debug("... Container created!");
        log.debug("end of getKieContainer method.");
        
        return kContainer;

}
```

Code we tried to delete the rules after each batch job  :

```
1)  KieFileSystem.delete(filePath+tenant+"//"+rulesFileName+"");
2)  kieServices.getRepository().removeModule(kContainer. getReleaseId());
```

But none of it is freeing up the RAM held by the Rules of each run.

Any help or suggestion would help.

Comment: Have you tried to dispose of the session kContainer.dispose()? are you sure, you have to load rules each time for the batch? As this is a bit expensive operation.

Comment: Yes We are disposing the container and the session both.

Comment: @NishitCharania We process a lot of data and the runs are batch jobs , so the rules change according to the data and the frequency of the run is not high.

Comment: I dont see memory leaks in my project, below is sample code that I am using
Integer executeSomeTypeOfRules(Integer fileIdentifier, Integer cloneId,
 KieSessionConfig kieSessionConfig) {
 KieSession kieSession = getSomeTypeOfRulesKieSession(fileIdentifier, recordCopyId);
 try {
   kieSessionConfig.setKieSession(kieSession);
   kieSessionConfig.config();
   int numberOfRules = kieSession.fireAllRules();
   return numberOfRules;} 
   finally {
   kieSession.dispose();}}
where we have make KieContainer as a cacheable, and that removed from the memory every day.
Hope this will help !

Comment: This is a pretty odd workflow, honestly. And slow because now you're intentionally taking the overhead of deploying rules before the batch runs.

Comment: Also your rules are apparently at `filePath+tenant+"/"+rulesFileName` but you're deleting `filePath+tenant+"//"+rulesFileName`, which may or may not matter, but may also indicate similar typos in other parts.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas This is the requirement since the rule set is different for each job run. Typos are there as i am not allowed to copy paste code from my coorporate network. Do you have any idea on KieServices.getRepository().removeModule(kContainer. getReleaseId()); why is it not removing the module from memory ?

Comment: Different rule sets for each job is pretty normal. Just fire the set you need instead of incurring the cost of unloading/reloading.